# Using WPF, how can I programmatically disable buttons that were created in XAML for a Listview control?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button

I created a WPF Listview and is populated with instances of ProductCategory.

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Next I create the list, populate it and assign it to the Listview control.

private List myProductList = new List();

// add some items to myProductList

// assign product list to ItemsSource property of a ListView

myListView.ItemsSource = myProductList;

In the XAML code, a button labelled "Edit" is added to each row. Each row represents an instance of ProductCategory:

```
    <ListView x:Name="myListView" Height="352" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1008">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CategoryName}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Created Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreatedDate}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Updated" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastUpdated}" Width="200"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Edit" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Edit" Click="EditCategory" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

When the user clicks the button, a dialog appears and the user can edit the data for an instance of ProductCategory. When the user closes the dialog, the user is returned to the Listview.

At this point I want to disable all the buttons in the Listview. How could I programmatically achieve this goal?

The buttons are not accessible in myListView.ItemsSource.

Comment: Your code suggestion worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the suggested solutions, here is the code to solve my problem:

```
    private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

            if (child != null && child is childItem)
            {
                return (childItem)child;
            }
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);

                if (childOfChild != null)
                {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void disableEditButtonsInListView()
    {
        myListView.Items.Cast<dynamic>().ToList().ForEach(item =>
        {
            var myListViewItem = (ListViewItem)(myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
            Button editButton = FindVisualChild<Button>(myListViewItem);
            if (editButton != null)
            {
                editButton.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        });
    }
```